# Music Visualizer

Tags: audio

I use my Raspberry Pi currently as a music station with Volumio. I would like to have an audio visualizer, which outputs the signal via the composite video jack.

Does someone know how to realize this? I don´t mind using another program than Volumio, but it has to have Airplay, NAS and Webradio support.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a fork of [shairport-sync](https://github.com/kwasmich/shairport-sync) which is an AirPlay client. You might want to take a look at it. It does some OpenGL audio visualizing. But it does not do anything more.

But to my understanding, Volumio is a collection of programs just like shairport-sync along with other. So I don't see a solution that covers all your audio paths.

Comment: I think it should be possible to write a simple program that is an audio sink, that does the same thing as my shariport-sync OpenGL audio visualizer. Then one only has to use an ALSA loopback device that redirects the audio output to the program with the audio sink along with the regular audio output.

Answer (score 0):

I've used python to get CAVA to display on the DOT3k LCD display, and display track info:

https://gist.github.com/transilluminate/d309b7f04b11230a3f6406a9cf70139c

Hope that helps get your project off the ground...